# how to set static attribute for db in model class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working with codeigniter, when I use `&get_instance` in my model it doesn't work always. Sometimes I have access to the database, at other times Codeigniter tells me that I must call Query method on string.

this when I try:

```
self::$db->query($sql);
```

My goal is to have static attribute db in my model class. That is my code

```
class My_Class extends CI_Model
{
  public static $db;

  public function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   self::$db=&get_instance()->db;
 }

}
```

Comment: please explain *"it doesn't work alltime"*? does it work never or only sometimes?

Comment: when i call my model in one controller it walk, in another controller it doesn't walk. i talk about &get_instance()->db, it return null value

Comment: maybe you want to edit your question with a **essential** version of both controllers and explain on which occasion that happens?

Answer (score 0):

apparently codeigniter loads a static db in the constructor only if a non static db has been loaded beforehand in another constructor of a model.

Reason why in some controller it worked and in others not.

To resolve my problem, I thus created a database model which I load automatically in autoload.php. Now it works the way I want!